trying to figure out what "last activity" actually was
This question is currently tagged with "L. Tyrone  4,298 modified 15 mins ago", but when I click through to the question I can't see any activity attributed to that user (edits, comments, answers, etc.) — in fact I don't see any signs of recent activity at all.
This meta question suggests a quickly deleted answer as the reason in a parallel case, but in this case I have high enough reputation that I'd expect to be able to see deleted answers ... what am I missing? Are there actions that would count as modification that would be invisible to me?


It was reopened by the user.

Thank you. Post as answer? How would I tell that?

I looked at the timeline for the question. The user was in the list of users who voted to reopen the question. They likely were the last user to do so, but to confirm that, I would have to find the reopen queue review.

TIL I learned about the timeline, about which I was absolutely ignorant despite having been here a while. Thanks! I would happily accept and upvote an answer.
